# How can I turn my Java app that runs in a terminal into a desktop app with a UI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I know that their are a bunch of different ways to do this, but I am getting pretty good at working with the terminal and want to move on to creating user interfaces and desktop apps! I have written an extremely cheesy and messy "number game" and would like to make it run in an applet with buttons and all of that jazz!

```
public static void gameStart()  {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Game of Awesome V1.2");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    spin();
}

public static void spin()   {

    int spinNum = (int)(10*Math.random());
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("type a number between 1 and 10:");
    int guessNum = input.nextInt();

    if(guessNum > 10)   {
        System.out.println(guessNum + " is greater than 10 you fool!");
                    spin();
    }else if(guessNum < 1)  {
        System.out.println(guessNum + " is less than 1 you fool!");
                    spin();
    }else   {

                System.out.println("\nSweet, looks like you chose [" + guessNum + "], good luck...");
                System.out.println("\ntype \"s\" to spin and \"quit\" to, quit...");
                String run = input2.nextLine();
            switch (run.toLowerCase()) {
                case "s":
                    System.out.println("\nyou spun [" + spinNum + "] and guessed [" + guessNum + "]!");
                    if(guessNum == spinNum) {
                        win();
                        askPlay();
                    }else   {
                            lose();
                            askPlay();
                    }
                    break;
                case "quit":
                    System.out.println("See ya later!");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("shit, you broke it! Luckily, I can fix this.");
                    askPlay();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
            }
            }
}

public static void askPlay()    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nWanna play again? (Type \"yes\" or \"no\")");
        String decideSpin = input.nextLine();

    switch (decideSpin.toLowerCase()) {
        case "yes":
            spin();
            break;
        case "no":
            System.out.println("\nI know it's a crappy game, thanks for playing though!");
            System.out.println();
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("\nI'm sorry,\nI was made by a lazy "
            + "programmer and can only understand \"yes\" or \"no\"..");
            askPlay();
            break;
    }
}

public static void win()    {
    System.out.println("\nWINNER: you won this insanley stupid game, of awesome! Be proud, winner. (:");
}

public static void lose()   {
    System.out.println("\nLOOOOOSSSSSEEEERRRR: yep, you stand with the majority with this loss.");
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: for some reason some of the code wouldn't show up... so the main method and imports are missing...

Comment: Have you any experience with applets and swing?

Comment: *"make it run in an applet"*  Make it run in a frame first.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you start by having a read through [Swing Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

The other thing you need to understand is Swing is event driven, unlike a console program where it tends to run sequentially

Answer (score 1):

Well, its simple: Start learning some of Java's GUI, I would recommend one of these two:

- [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html)
- [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely start learning Swing. This is the standard Java GUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running it in [Processing](http://processing.org/) (a Java Library/Applet). That's perhaps the fastest most simplest way to get something up and going. You can even export it as an app if you like. Cheers!